# Find $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ for coprime integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> How can you find the $\gcd(a,b)$ for $a,b$ coprime integers in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$?

I tried to find a divisor of $1$ but I get some messy equations with very little information.

Comment: If they're truly coprime, then the gcd is 1.  Otherwise, I would look at the norm function $N(x+y\sqrt{-3})=x^2+3y^2$, which is multiplicative.  Hence if $c$ divides both $a,b$, then $N(c)$ divides both $N(a)$ and $N(b)$.

Comment: They are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ are such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then they are also coprime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$. If $z\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$, and $z\mid a$, $z\mid b$, then $N(z)\mid a^2$ and $N(z)\mid b^2$. But $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$, so $N(z)=1$ hence $z$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.